# How to manipulate a webpage using a console application?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, console-application

If I were to be making a program which tells the user how many search results inputted search terms have in Google: how could a console application load a web-page in the background, type into a text-box, and then press a button?

Is it possible to manipulate a webbrowser from either winforms or WPF in a console application?

Comment: You could use something like WatiN [link](http://watin.org/). It can do Console and Winforms but does not appear to have been updated in a long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can i.e. use wget or curl (downloadable GNU tools) and make a query like this:

https://www.google.de/?q=Hallo

CURL is additionally a library for this (it is even available in PHP)

Additionally .NET has a webbrowser component

Comment: Sorry - I'm not actually making a program that tells how many search results there are, but it's easier to pretend I am rather then explaining what I'm really doing. What I really want is to use an online textbox and button similarly to what is on the Google homepage